# How to create .oni file from raw depth data?

Tags: openni, nite

In a research project I am working on, we are getting raw depth data from a sensor, which is not a kinect or other consumer sensor. This raw depth data consists of unsigned 16 bit array where each element has distance data in mm.

In order to process the data, I am planning to convert these data from a .bin format into .oni format, so that I can utilize some algorithms provided by openNI and NiTE. We receive data over TCP/IP.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I'm interested.. thanks!